# How do I position a block of text after my CSS word-scrolling animation?

Tags: html, css, animation, spacing

I am looking to make a rotating text animation that says "THE ___ABILITY LAB" while rotating through words such as "adaptABILITY, affordABILITY, employABILITY" etc.

I followed a tutorial that allowed me to create a scrolling text animation, but only at the end of a sentence, allowing me to create text like "THE adapt", but I am having complications making the "ABILITY LAB" part appear after. Given that the words "adapt, afford, employ" have different amounts of characters, I would like them to appear at a constant distance between the remaining "ability lab", and of course not overlap any text.

Below, is my HTML and CSS code. Thank you!

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.box
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.word
{
  display: inline-block;
  color: grey;
}
.word span
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes animate
{
  0%
  {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  2%
  {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  18%
  {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20%
  {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100%
  {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
.word span:nth-child(1)
{
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.word span:nth-child(2)
{
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.word span:nth-child(3)
{
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.word span:nth-child(4)
{
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.word span:nth-child(5)
{
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
```

```html
<!docctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rotating Word</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      THE
      <div class="word">
        <span>adapt </span>
        <span>explor</span>
        <span>employ</span>
      </div>
      ABILITY LAB
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us better understand: What happens with your code the way it is now? I assume you don't get an error message. In what way is it failing to work as you want?

Don't respond to this comment, by the way. Instead, please edit the information into your main post so everyone will see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the distance between "THE" and "ABILITY LAB" to always be constant, simply give your `.word` div a `width`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/js50aLph/.

---

### Right-Aligning the Text

To right-align the variable text (i.e. "adapt", "afford", "employ") so that there is no space between it and "AFFORD", you can try this:

First, make `.word` `position: relative` so that we can position the text relative to it.

```css
.word {
  position: relative;
  /* ... */
}
```

Second, position the `<span>` elements to the right and bottom:

```
.word span {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0; /* After adding this, you should remove top: 0 */
  /* ... */
}
```

The `bottom: 0` is needed because `.word` has no height. Thus, positioning, the `<span>` relative to the *top* of word would cause it to become offset.

Lastly, with this solution, you will now likely notice that the text is not correctly vertically aligned. To solve this, just adjust the `bottom` property of the `<span>` element. For example:

```
.word span {
  /* ... */
  bottom: -12px;
}
```

An Updated Example: https://jsfiddle.net/js50aLph/1/.

An Updated Example (With Correct Vertical Offset): https://jsfiddle.net/j2x7bkag/.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The issue that I am facing is that when I use this solution, there is more space between "employ" and "ABILITY" than there is in "adapt" and "ABILITY". I am hoping to make it so that there is no spaces in the words "adaptABILITY, affordABILITY, employABILITY"

Comment: @NicholasNyvall I added information on aligning the text; let me know if it works.

Comment: @NicholasNyvall certainly. Also, I added some more information to the answer that you may wish to check out. And if the answer helped you, you can mark it as the correct one by clicking the checkmark icon.